# How I can get value that is posted to my URL by some other website

Tags: asp.net

Below is scenario when doing 3DS authentication in Moneris. They will send the data in my url which I have given to them. How can I get  the value in my asp.net app.

Cavv Lookup Request – mpiCavvLookup
(Challenge Flow Only)

In the challenge flow, the 3DS server will POST a “cres” value back to the notificationURL provided in the threeDSAuthentication request once the cardholder has completed the challenge. The “cres” is then posted to the Moneris 3DS server in the CavvLookup request, the response to this request will include the result of the challenge, which will include the eci and the cavv if the challenge was successful.

How can I get the above mentioned "cres" value in my asp.net application.

Comment: can you please add some code?

Comment: I do not have any code and do not have any idea that how it can be done.

Comment: I got this from my initial request

ResponseCode = 001
ReceiptId = Test1597873519352
Message = SUCCESS
MessageType = ARes
TransStatus = C
ChallengeURL = https://acs-server.ps.msignia.com/api/v1/browser_challenges
ChallengeData = eyJhY3NUcmFuc0lEIjoiMjkwNTZlMzItNWFiOC00NGZlLThmZWItYjliYmNjOGYyNTZjIiwiY2hhbGxlbmdlV2luZG93U2l6ZSI6IjA1IiwibWVzc2FnZVR5cGUiOiJDUmVxIiwibWVzc2FnZVZlcnNpb24iOiIyLjEuMCIsInRocmVlRFNTZXJ2ZXJUcmFuc0lEIjoiYjY5Y2NiNmUtOTY4Yy00OTExLWE5MTctZjQ3Mzk0ZDU3YmIyIn0=
ThreeDSServerTransId = b69ccb6e-968c-4911-a917-f47394d57bb2

Comment: and send this data in form post:

<form method="POST" action="@ViewBag.challangeUrl">
    <input name="creq" value="@ViewBag.chalangeData">
    <input type="submit" title="Submit" />
</form>

Comment: I have redirected to a page 

https://acs-server.ps.msignia.com/api/v1/browser_challenges
after entering security code on this site , I have been redirected to url of my app give by me in code. 
They say that they will post a "cres" value on my URL. How can I get that value?